# How do I go to boot settings In Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation

I want to change my Ubuntu architecture from x32 to x64 thus wanted to boot from a live disk. Pressing F2 takes me to a screen giving Ubuntu Advanced Options and memtest

Comment: Boot settings vary from one manufacturer to another; could be F6, F10, F11, F12 as well. However, boot settings won't get you where you need to go, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from 32-bit to 64-bit will require a complete reinstallation of Ubuntu.
Start with downloading the [64-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso).
Once downloaded, [verify the ISO downloaded without corruption](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).
When you know you have a correctly downloaded ISO, [make a LiveUSB from that ISO](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0).
Once the LiveUSB is created, make a complete backup of all your data.
When you have verified the backup, then reboot your PC and boot from the LiveUSB.
The Ubiquity installer will allow you to preserve the 32-bit installation and install the 64-bit version alongside the 32-bit. Choose that option.
Once the installation is complete, reboot into the 64-bit version and test it.
If satisfactory, then copy the data from the 32-bit's /home folders to the 64-bit /home and remove the 32-bit installation, giving its space to the 64-bit.